# rails check_box_tag to include existing values of from array of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following tag in a nested form

```
<%= check_box_tag "friend_ids[]", ff.id, @contentrestrictions.friends.include?(ff.id) %>
```

is handling the following array of records

```
>> @contentrestrictions

[
#<Contentrestriction id: 29, usercontent_id: nil, friend_id: nil, created_at: "2019-04-28 10:55:32", updated_at: "2019-04-28 10:55:32">, 
#<Contentrestriction id: 30, usercontent_id: nil, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2019-04-28 10:55:32", updated_at: "2019-04-28 10:55:32">, 
#<Contentrestriction id: 31, usercontent_id: nil, friend_id: 4, created_at: "2019-04-28 10:55:32", updated_at: "2019-04-28 10:55:32">]
```

Even though

```
class Contentrestriction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :friend, optional: true
```

`@contentrestrictions.` followed by any of `friend_id, friend_ids` both appended with or without `[]`  all lead to NoMethodError: undefined method for Array.

how can this `include` function get a proper array to work with?

Comment: `<%= check_box_tag "friend_ids[]", ff.id, @contentrestrictions.pluck(:friend_id).include?(ff.id) %>`. Consider asign `@contentrestrictions.pluck(:friend_id)` to a variable if used more than one time in the template.

Comment: Goodness gracious!  I use `pluck` all the time, but it did not dawn on me here!

Answer (score 1):

the issue is in this line:

```
@contentrestrictions.friends.include?(ff.id)
```

you are comparing a friend object with a friend id, you could use `pluck` to get the friend ids, or you could just compare the objects:

```
@contentrestrictions.friends.include?(ff)
```

this will make a query for the `.friends` and you could remove this query by pre-loading the `friends` association, e.g. `eager_load(:friends)` or `includes(:friends)`